# No returned data for a range of more than 6h

Tags: graphite

I use graphite 0.9.15.

I have metrics with few data (many nulls) over the last 6 hours, I can draw them when querying the last 6 hours, but if I ask for more (like 7 hours), I have no data. I tried to change the consolidation function with `consolidateBy` to `max`, but I have still no data. What should I do to plot my data over more than 6 hours?

I configured the storage aggregation with a `xFilesFactor` of 0 and the `aggregationMethod` to max, but my data are too young to be aggregated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong with your [storage-schemas.conf](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-schemas-conf). E.g.  you have only 6 hours of data there - "retentions = 1m:6h"

Or [aggregation scheme](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf) also can be wrong - if your lowest retention is 10 seconds, and you sending data e.g. every 60 seconds then you will get one data point, and then five empty points - 80% of data is empty. Default xFilesFactor is 0.5, so it will discard your data if you have more than 50% of empty points.

Usually, your lowest retention should match with your metrics rate - or you need to set up proper aggregation for different metrics by regex.

Comment: The retention config is : `retentions = 10s:6h, 1min:7d, 10min:5y`

Comment: Graphite doesn't understand 'min' as time suffix, should be just 'm' - http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html

So, please try `retentions = 10s:6h, 1m:7d, 10m:5y`

Comment: And you need to delete and recreate existing wsp files in Graphite storage dir - existing files will not be changed.

Comment: It's strange, it was the default configuration.

Comment: Well, it's not the default, it was copied from [statsd doc](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md).

Comment: Yes, I was wrong - according to [code](https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/blob/3842535f689282e9fff3d180dce6b0fedfb5c932/whisper.py#L136-L166) any value should work. You can try to run `whisper-info.py` utility against some of your wsp files to check how many archives do you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121103/discussion-between-deniszh-and-jazz).